# Unrecognized database format In MS Access due to multiple locks functioning on the database file at the same time

Tags: c#, ms-access, networking

Hello Everyone
I have created a c# application with `MS-Access` database. But when I run it on network where multiple clients access the database at same time, following error occurred some times.
`Unrecognized database format`
 I researched this topic a lot and found that this issue is happening due to `multiple locks functioning on the database file at the same time`.
How can I overcome this. Please suggest.
Edit: When I try to open the database it shows some type of corruption and displays the following message
 `Microsoft Access has detected that this database is in an inconsistent state, and will attempt to recover the database`

Comment: @June7 I have done the same thing as suggested there but still the same issue. Check my edit

Comment: Here's another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725607/recent-rash-of-microsoft-access-database-files-in-an-inconsistent-state

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have been hit by the well-known *lease bug* being around for years. A good summarise can be found at Daniel's blog:

[Access – Bug – Database is in an Unrecognized Format](https://www.devhut.net/2018/06/13/access-bug-database-is-in-an-unrecognized-format/)

The current status is, unfortunately, quo.